# Looking at just EC Public Key parameters, how can you tell if it is invalid?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am trying to handle when a parsers goes off the rails and reads an EC public keys wrong (just the X and Y components, I know the curve prior).

Right now I check for the following (false means invalid):

1. Is the key even on the Curve?
2. Is the Public Key X component less than the Curve's Base Point X?

I am pretty confident in #1, but not as confident in #2. #2 was just made by never seeing a case that contradicted it.

So my question is, 1) are these two checks correct? 2) are there other checks that can detect bad public keys?

Comment: Yeah that's not the curve I am using, but still useful. I am currently looking at P256.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The general rule for curves is given in;

- [2003 - Validation of Elliptic Curve Public Keys](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-36288-6_16) by Adrian Antipa,Daniel Brown, Alfred Menezes, and René StruikScott Vanstone

  They defined a point is valid if

  1. $P \neq \mathcal{O}$
  2. The $x$ and $y$ coordinates of $P$, $x(P),y(P)$ are valid elements of the field.
  3. $P$ satisfies the curve equation - against the twist attack
  4. Check $[n]P = \mathcal{O}$ for prime curves ($h=1$) and check $[h]P \neq \mathcal{O}$ for non-prime curves ($h>1$) where $h$ is the cofactor $h = \#E(k)/n$

if 1,2, and 3 are verified and $h=1$ (i.e. prime curve) then the 4th is already satisfied.

Comment: First off, thank you. Ok to dumb these down greatly:
1) Make sure the public key is not an identify/infinity point
2) Make sure the X and Y of the public key are greater than 0 and less than the curve's prime
3) Make sure the point is on the curve 
I am dealing with h=1 so I did not look into #4.

Comment: @LiamKelly Valid includes 0, the first case eliminated the identity, see [here that](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87545/18298) there are 3 points with $x=0$ with one of them is the identity.